# Why are multiple nested states been created in my Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is the authReducer i have

```
function signinReducer(state={userInfo:[]},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_SIGNIN_REQ:
            return {loading:true};
        case USER_SIGNIN_SUCC:
            return {loading:false,userInfo:action.payload}
        case USER_SIGNIN_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
        default:
            return{state};
    }
}
```

the initialState of the store

```
const initialState={};
```

all the reducers

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productReducer,
    productDetailRed,
    cartReducer,
    authReducer
})
```

Why are multiple nested state been added to my authReducer, it starts with just 1 state and with every time i move to a different component a new nested state gets added. Pls help
[image: store]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return state instead of { state } in default case :

```
function signinReducer(state={userInfo:[]},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_SIGNIN_REQ:
            return {loading:true};
        case USER_SIGNIN_SUCC:
            return {loading:false,userInfo:action.payload}
        case USER_SIGNIN_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked , this is embarrassing, making such silly mistake